# GameCenter showsCompletionBanner keeps showing

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

In my game (I'm using `SpriteKit`, and therefore only support `iOS 7`), when a player reaches his first 10 points, he is awarded with an achievement. I've implemented the achievement method as follows:

```
-(void) First10Points
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: @"Achievement_First10Points"];

    if (achievement)
    {
        achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;
        achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;

        NSArray *achievements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:achievement, nil];

        [GKAchievement reportAchievements:achievements withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error in reporting achievements: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

This works fine and the achievement is indeed earned at 10 points, with the game center banner indicating this to the player during the game. However, when the banner disappears it reappears after a second or so and continues to do so until i terminate the game. The game can still be played while it does this loop thing. I can't seem to understand why it does this and I have not come across this problem while searching the web.
Anyone an idea? Or should I implement my achievements in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that you're calling the `First10Points` method multiple times. You should check if the player has already reached the 10 points achievement before presenting the achievement again. If they have indeed already reached it, then don't call the method.

Try adding a variable like `BOOL first10 = NO;` When you run your check `(score == 10)`, set `first10 = YES;` Everytime before you call `First10Points`, ensure that `(first10 == NO)`

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to implement that? I'm calling it now with if (score == 10), which is only true at one moment during the game, right? Or do I have to stop it calling the method once it has started?

Comment: If that check `(score == 10)` is run again before their score goes up, then it would cause the problem. I've edited my answer to show how to fix this.

Comment: Great! Implementing a BOOL makes sure it only runs the code once. It was, indeed, checking it multiple times. Thanks

Comment: @Harold can you show example of how you fixed it? I have the same problem!